# Greater Than program

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a program that when given two numbers will tell you witch is greater or if they are equal. When I run the code bellow it doesn't work with any numbers above ten

```
print "Please give me your first number."
first_number = gets.chomp 


print "Please give me your second number."
second_number = gets.chomp 

if first_number == second_number
    print "These two are equal."
elsif first_number > second_number
    print "Your first number is greater." 
elsif first_number < second_number
    print "Your second number is greater."
end
```

Comment: Convert each string input to a number. e.g. `first_number.to_i`, then do the comparison. And btw use `puts` instead of `print` and two-spaces for indentation.

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't a useful problem description. How specifically does it *not work*?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
print "Please give me your first number."
first_number = gets.to_i 

print "Please give me your second number."
second_number = gets.to_i 

puts case first_number <=> second_number
     when -1
       "Your second number is greater."
     when 0
       "These two are equal."
     when 1
       "Your first number is greater."
     end
```

As others have mentioned, `gets` returns a string, so for comparisons you must convert the string to an integer. Also, see [Integer#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Comment: I realize that the value returned by <=> is not likely to change in future Ruby versions, but I'm still a little paranoid relying on fixed values (i.e. the number 1) here. I'd be more comfortable with a `> 0` and `< 0` test. I suppose if we did that then an `if` clause would make more sense than a `case` clause.

Comment: `<=>` (defined for various classes) is a widely-used method; you should not hesitate to use it (i.e., get over your reluctance to do so). The class [Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html) defines  `<` and `>`, but for other classes (e.g., custom classes) one defines  `<=>` for the class and `include`s the module [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html). The first paragraph of its doc explains how it that module works. `<=>` is also commonly used with [Enumerable#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and other methods.

Comment: It's not the <=> operator I tend to avoid, it's assuming that the value will always be -1, 0, or 1. I prefer tests of < 0, == 0, or > 0. It may be habit from older languages (Java, C++, C, I don't remember), who had comparison implementations that relied on the subtraction of values for which normalizing to -1 and 1 was unnecessary and time consuming. But I guess if the language states that it is, and always will be -1, 0, or 1, then I shouldn't hesitate to rely on that. (Does it?)

Comment: Yes, the method always returns `-1`, `0` or `1`, nothing else, and if that were ever changed the streets would be filled with Rubiests bearing torches and pitchforks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Isn't it spelled Rub*yists*? Or maybe in that scenario they'd turn into Ru*beasts* :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the result of `gets.comp` is a string, `>` and `<` alphabetically compare the inputs like in a dictionary. The following is a list of strings alphabetically sorted:

```
"1"
"10"
"1300930184"
"2"
"2139182"
"23"
"3"
"aardvark"
"ab"
"avalanche"
"caramel"
```

What you want instead is to convert the strings to a whole number (Integer) and then compare those. This can be done e.g. by wrapping the call to chomp like this: `first_number = Integer(gets.chomp)`

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the inputs (as explained above in other answers) I'd suggest this reporting approach, which more precisely addresses the question, and avoids the need for explicit comparisons:

```
if first_number == second_number
  puts "The numbers are equal."
else
  higher_number = [first_number, second_number].max
  puts "#{higher_number} is the higher number."
end
```

(Though I admit that getting the max of an array may be a reach for someone on the level of this question.)